# Dot product of Perpendicular vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors, inner-products

Can someone please explain to me why the dot product of two perpendicular vectors are zero regardless of their magnitude ? I don't seem to understand how the magnitude of the vectors that generally have an effect on the dot product , is nullified if the vectors are perpendicular.

Can someone explain with an example and a visualization ?

Comment: That's because the dot product is the product of the magnitudes times the cosine of the angle of the vectors.

Comment: @Bharathi A Rather than a mere visualisation you should assimilate the fact that the inner product depends not only on the norms (magnitudes) of the vectors but also on their relative geometric position, more explicitly on the angle they make! In particular cases, special values of the angle alone suffice to annihilate the entire inner product between the two vectors, regardless of their norms.

Comment: What is your definition of the dot product ?

Comment: Here's an analogous phenomenon: usually, the harder you push on a cart, the faster it moves (more accurately the more it accelerates). However, if you push straight down onto the cart (initially at rest), then the speed of the cart will stay at zero no matter how hard you push.

Answer (score 1):

Geometrically, one can think dot product as projection of one vector to other.
Say, vector a is perpendicular to vector b, then vector a will have zero projection on vector b and vice versa.,(imagine shining a torch light from one to another).

Put a rod on floor,
Case 1) rod is kept vertical, and shine a torch light kept at top of rod,shining  towards floor, will you see any length of rod on floor(length of shadow of rod)? Regardless of length of rod, you will always see a point( which is 0 length).

Case 2) rod is inclined say θ with horizontal, you will now see some non zero length as shadow of rod, which is projection of rod on floor. It can be obtained from dot product calculation.

Answer (score 1):

By linearity of the dot product $$\lambda\vec u\cdot\mu\vec v=(\lambda\mu)(\vec u\cdot\vec v)$$

and $$\vec u\cdot\vec v=0\implies\lambda\vec u\cdot\mu\vec v=0.$$

so that the magnitude of orthogonal vectors does not matter.

---

Now the explanation of why a dot product can be zero depends on the definition that you use (Cartesian, geometric, trigonometric...). But if you admit that a dot product can be negative, then by continuity it can be zero as well.